# IBM Watson speech to text failed Authentication

Tags: ios, authentication, ibm-cloud, speech-to-text

Hi, I created a new service at Ibm watson for speech to text.

But when I am using the "service credentials" I am getting this error :

> Error Domain=com.ibm.watson.developer-cloud.WatsonDeveloperCloud Code=0 "Failed to obtain an authentication token. Check credentials." UserInfo={NSLocalizedFailureReason=Failed to obtain an authentication token. Check credentials.}﻿

To add, over IBM watson in "Service Access Authorisation" it shows this  ----> *Speech_To_Text-1d is not currently authorized to access other service instances.*

How can I resolve this authentication problem?

Answer (score 0):

And old question, for those who find this searching, you probably want to use the Watson Swift SDK (https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/swift-sdk), which handles authentication (and new credential formats).